# Is there are "sphere" associated to any topological vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

If I have a topological vector space that is not locally compact, is it still possible to associate to it some natural "sphere" like object?

For locally compact Hausdorff spaces, the my first guess was the one-point compactification. But this is uninteresting since locally compact Hausdorff spaces are finite dimensional.

Thanks for satisfying my vague curiousity.

Comment: This question is too vague if and only if its answer is “no.”

Comment: @k.stm If a question can be answered with "no," then it is not vague, since it can be interpreted decisively.

Comment: That was only a joke, of course, so let’s not get into that too deep, but the point I was trying to make is that, in my view, this question can be answered if and only if it can be answered positively (because such an answer would consist of some sort of construction of a sphere-like object which would most likely satisfy your curiosity). If the answer is “no,” then it seems utterly hopeless to devise a sufficiently precise notion of sphere-like objects and prove that there isn’t a definite way to associate such sphere-like objects to topological vector spaces.

Comment: … with “yes”, you won’t have to go specifically into the notion of “sphere-like objects”, with “no” you would have to. So the vagueness of sphere-like objects only becomes critical if the answer really is “no.” (Now I’m going to sleep.)

Comment: @k.stm My response was also a joke. I'm glad that we are on the same page now. :)

Comment: Being precise about sphere like objects is somewhat simple: a construction that gives $S^n$ from $R^n$ for all $n$, and that can also be applied to a TVS.

Comment: In normed vector spaces you have $S=\lbrace x\in X: \|x\|=1\rbrace$.

Comment: @Jochen But that is the $n-1$ sphere in the $R^n$ case, so the "dimension" is not what I wanted. Thanks though...